# Adding missing period in the data using Pandas and fill values with Zeros. How can I then select each segment to manipulation

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe

I have not used pandas to solve complex problems relating to my data(SQL was my preferred choice till now). I was solving this problem where

[Input I receive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQk8E.png)

```
Column1|Column2|Column3|Column4|Column5|Period|Value1|Value2|Value3
A1|B1|C1|D1|E1|0|10|10|10
A1|B1|C1|D1|E1|1|10|10|10
A1|B1|C1|D1|E1|3|10|10|10
A2|B2|C2|D2|E2|0|10|10|10
A2|B2|C2|D2|E2|1|10|10|10
A2|B2|C2|D2|E2|2|10|10|10
A2|B2|C2|D2|E2|4|10|10|10
```

The output I want to have is this . So i want to add the missing period for each segment
A segment is like (A1&B1&C1&D1&E1).

[Output i want to produce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EpYu.png)

```
Column1|Column2|Column3|Column4|Column5|Period|Value1|Value2|Value3
A1|B1|C1|D1|E1|0|10|10|10
A1|B1|C1|D1|E1|1|10|10|10
A1|B1|C1|D1|E1|2|0|0|0
A1|B1|C1|D1|E1|3|10|10|10
A2|B2|C2|D2|E2|0|10|10|10
A2|B2|C2|D2|E2|1|10|10|10
A2|B2|C2|D2|E2|2|10|10|10
A2|B2|C2|D2|E2|3|0|0|0
A2|B2|C2|D2|E2|4|10|10|10
```

After this i wanted to take each segment and wanted to perform some calculation on the Value columns. I have seem some of the answers in this forum but this particular kind of scenario has not been asked here.
In SQL I can use PARTITION BY to get to my desired objective. But I am finding it it difficult to do it in pandas (or may be i am too ignorant wrt pandas)

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

We can use [`Dataframe.unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) + [`DataFrame.stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)

```
new_df = df.set_index(df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('Period|Column', 
                                                         regex=True)].tolist())\
           .unstack(fill_value=0).stack()\
           .reset_index().reindex(df.columns, axis=1)
```

Or:

```
new_df = df.set_index(['Column5', 'Period'])\
           .unstack().stack(dropna=False)\
           .reset_index().reindex(df.columns, axis=1)
new_df = new_df.assign(**new_df.loc[:, 'Period':].fillna(0))\
               .assign(**new_df.loc[:, :'Period'].ffill())
print(new_df)
```

---

```
  Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5  Period  Value1  Value2  Value3
0      A1      B1      C1      D1      E1       0    10.0    10.0    10.0
1      A1      B1      C1      D1      E1       1    10.0    10.0    10.0
2      A1      B1      C1      D1      E1       2     0.0     0.0     0.0
3      A1      B1      C1      D1      E1       3    10.0    10.0    10.0
4      A1      B1      C1      D1      E1       4     0.0     0.0     0.0
5      A2      B2      C2      D2      E2       0    10.0    10.0    10.0
6      A2      B2      C2      D2      E2       1    10.0    10.0    10.0
7      A2      B2      C2      D2      E2       2    10.0    10.0    10.0
8      A2      B2      C2      D2      E2       3     0.0     0.0     0.0
9      A2      B2      C2      D2      E2       4    10.0    10.0    10.0
```